# Is there an Antlr Grammar available for LLVM IR?

Tags: antlr, llvm-ir

I want to parse a LLVM IR file and perform certain operation accordingly, Wondering if there is an ANTLR Grammar available for LLVM IR, this will make my job much simpler?

Comment: LLVM is really modular. You can use libraries to make your parsing/operations in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this file from one of the github repositories:
https://github.com/rwl/JLLVM/blob/master/src/cn/edu/sjtu/jllvm/VMCore/Parser/LLVM.g

It is a part of JLLVM source code(JLLVM is a Java version of LLVM Core. To get more info about JLLVM you should follow the link: http://tcloud.sjtu.edu.cn/wiki/index.php/User:Liuhaots:JLLVM)

Answer (score 1):

The largest repository of grammars I know of [is here.](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)  I don't see your grammar in the list, sorry.  Terence Parr [makes mention of it in this article](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/LLVM), but that's all I can find, but it's quite old and seems to be based on ANTLR3.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. Quitre useful